# willDisplayCell won't change background color consistent with logic

Tags: ios, objective-c, background, uitableview

I've tried just about everything I can think of, googled lots, searched SO, and still can't find the solution. Here's the issue:

I have a custom `UITableViewCell` with several labels in it. The text varies dynamically, and the background color (of the cell, not the labels) should vary as well. The text changes in the labels work fine. However, the BG color won't change no matter what I do. The only upside is that I don't feel that lonely. This is apparently a mystery even to a few high-rep people. I'm hoping someone here has found a solution (or can point out my mistake).

Here's what I have done:

Put the logic inside `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. Disappointment.

Googled and SO'd some more, then:

Put the logic inside a `willDisplayCell` call. Nothing.

Googled more, then:

Put the logic back into `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. Nada.

Put the logic inside the `willDisplayCell` call again. No go.

Found a post on SO that suggested putting another view in the custom cell to cover the original background and set it to change with logic. It didn't.

Tried putting the logic back into `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

Tried using a `switch` statement in the logic.

Tried using `if, else if, else` in the logic.

Several other things I can't remember. Still doesn't work.

Yes, the `UItableViewdelegate` is set.

Here's the current code, which also doesn't work:

**EDIT: Made a slight change in the top if statement to reflect the suggestion by @Adrian below. Unfortunately, it didn't cure the problem.**

```
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    id<NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [[detailFRC sections] objectAtIndex:section];
    return [sectionInfo numberOfObjects];
    NSLog(@"There are %lu objects in the frc",(unsigned long)[sectionInfo numberOfObjects]);
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CustomCell * cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"myCustomCell"];
    if (!cell)
    {
        [tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"CustomCell" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"myCustomCell"];
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"myCustomCell"];
    }


    return cell;
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(CustomCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    thisActivity = [detailFRC objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (self.activityOrCategory == 0)
    {

            if (thisActivity.name == self.detailFocusItem)
            {
            [cell.myBGView setBackgroundColor:Rgb2UIColor(255, 215, 215)]; // Light red
            cell.backgroundView = cell.myBGView;
            }
            else if (thisActivity.name == self.detailBenchmarkItem)
            {
                [cell.myBGView setBackgroundColor:Rgb2UIColor(215, 220, 255)]; // Light blue
            }
            else
            {
                cell.myBGView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
            }
    }

    else if (self.activityOrCategory == 1)

    {
            if (thisActivity.category == self.detailFocusItem)
            {
                cell.myBGView.backgroundColor = Rgb2UIColor(255, 235, 200);
            }
            else if (thisActivity.category == self.detailBenchmarkItem)
            {
                cell.myBGView.backgroundColor = Rgb2UIColor(200, 255, 200);
            }
            else
            {
                cell.myBGView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
            }
    }

    NSLog(@"cell.backgroundColor is %@",cell.backgroundColor);
    NSLog(@"This row says %@",thisActivity.name);
    cell.activityLabel.text = thisActivity.name;
    cell.categoryLabel.text = thisActivity.category;

    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat: @"MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss"];

    cell.fromDateLabel.text = [dateFormat stringFromDate:thisActivity.startTime];
    cell.toDateLabel.text = [dateFormat stringFromDate:thisActivity.stopTime];
    }
```

Many thanks for taking the time to look! All help appreciated, even if it's my stupid mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope those who looked at and especially those who took the time to answer this question can have a sense of humor about this:

It turns out that both of the answers graciously contributed above will work (with minor mods). I feel like a bit of a dummy, but the problem I was encountering wasn't with the setting of the background color, it was with the logic itself. Namely, I was using this code in my if statement:

```
 if (thisActivity.name == self.detailFocusItem)
```

when, since both the objects in question are `NSStrings`, it should have been:

```
 if ([thisActivity.name isEqualToString:self.detailFocusItem])
```

Thus, control was simply skipping the color-setting code. :/

I really do apologize for taking your time.

OTOH, had it not been for having been forced to take a new look at it as I implemented your suggestions, I don't know how long it might have taken me to see the forest instead of the trees.

You both get upvotes, and I hope you'll be gentle and chalk it up to the inexperience of a nooby enthusiast.

Many thanks for helping!

Answer (score 1):

I was under the impression that a UITableViewCell has an actual property of backgroundView, I can see you have something called BGView, but I can't see anywhere from your example where the cell property gets set.

So all I can say is that for my examples where I have done this, I always create a UIView and set it's colour, then assign it to the backgroundView property.

I hope  this might be of some help and that I didn't miss you doing that in your example earlier!

```
//   Effectively draws the cell with a red background
UIView *backView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 44)];
backView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
cell.backgroundView = backView;
```

Thanks
Adrian_H

Comment: I already had a UIView as a property on the custom cell, but you're right in that I hadn't set the cell.backgroundView to it. I just did, but the result is still no change in the bg color.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, i'm guessing it would then be a tableview property.  My question would be, does it work in the simulator when using iOS 6.1?  My reasoning behind this is that they changed a lot of the styling properties with iOS 7 and I wonder if your efforts are getting un-done by an overall property.

Comment: Haven't ever tried it in iOS 6, so don't know. Maybe someone else here can chime in with an answer on that. Thanx, @adrian!

Comment: Try creating a new view as opposed to setting one already in existence on the generated cell,  I think that might be it

Answer (score 1):

I never use Rgb2UIColor before, I don't know how it works.

Try the below code, it works on my app:-

inside **willDisplayCell**

```
CGFloat nRed=255/255.f;
CGFloat nGreen= 215/255.f;
CGFloat nBlue = 215/255.f;
UIColor * myColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:nRed green:nGreen blue:nBlue alpha:1]; //Light Red

cell.textLabel.backgroundColor = myColor;
cell.detailTextLabel.backgroundColor = myColor;
cell.backgroundColor =myColor;
[cell.backgroundView setBackgroundColor:myColor];
```